A stochastic optimal control problem with filtering-like dynamics
I want to extend the following stochastic optimal control problem with randomized feedback control to the continuous time case
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{H}}&\bigg[\int_0^T\frac{1}{4\beta}|v_t|^2\mathrm{d}t  +g(Y_T)\bigg|Y_0=x\bigg]\\
v_t&=\mu_\theta(Y_t)+\sigma_\theta(Y_t)\cdot\xi,\quad\xi\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_d)\\dY_t&=[-\nabla V(Y_t)+2\beta v_t]dt+\sqrt{2\beta}dW_t,
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{H}}$ represents that this expectation is taken with respect to both $Y_t$ and $\xi$.
I try to convert it to a problem like this(not very sure if it is well defined)
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad &\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{H}}[\frac{1}{4\beta}\int_0^{T}|{v_t}|^2 dt+g(Y_{T})|Y_0=x]\\
dv_t&=\mu_{\theta}(Y_t)dt+\sigma_{\theta}(Y_t)d\breve{W}_t\\
dY_t&=[-\nabla V(Y_t)+2\beta v_t]dt+\sqrt{2\beta}dW_t
\end{align}
where $W_t$ and $\breve{W}_t$ are independent Brownian motions. And $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{H}}$ is taken with respect to both $Y_t$ and $v_t$.
The form of its dynamics reminds me of the dynamics of the filtering problem. However, I cannot find any references to stochastic control theory to solve a problem with such dynamics.
My question is, are there any papers, books, or any material that includes a problem similar to this? Is there a name for this kind of control problem? Are there any theories dealing with it? Or, is there a better alternative to extend it to a continuous case?
Thanks in advance.

If you are interpreting $v_{t}$ to be the control and the design freedom is only on parameter $\theta$, then it is indeed in nonstandard stochastic optimal control form in the sense the controller is a "dynamic" feedback. Also, possible typo: missing minus in front of $\nabla V$.

Thank you for pointing out my typo. By the way, what do you mean by "dynamic" and how does it make the problem nonstandard? I am not very sure about how to express it very rigorously.

I am assuming that you interpret $v_t$ as control. If so, the standard formulation is simply minimize the objective subject to the controlled dynamics on state $Y_t$. Solution of that problem will be deterministic Markov policy $v_t(t,Y_t)$ which can be seen as a "static" state-time map that maps current time $t$ and current state $Y_t$ to optimal control/decision $v_t$. If needed, you can then write the dynamics of $v_t$ as an SDE by applying Itô's rule. This is the standard way. I am not sure what is your motivation behind writing $v_t$ as SDE at the formulation level.

This control issue arises in a reinforcement learning context, where a stochastic policy and entropy regularization are commonly employed to encourage the agent to explore and receive more learning signals. Typically, a Gaussian distribution is used to parameterize the stochastic policy at each timestep ( t ). In this instance, I am attempting to adapt it to a continuous-time scenario. While I have not encountered any SDEs similar to the first system, I have observed ones akin to the second system in filtering applications, so transform it accordingly.
